# PHP Oauth API to login via Hotmail Account

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, hotmail

Like a facebook , twitter, yahoo accounts, how we can login via MSN/Hotmail account instead to register for a new account? to get the username and save the data behalf this name, using `php/mysql`?

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below url to download the code written in PHP/Mysql:

http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/42421.html

Comment: Well noted. Thank you.